# Is normal distribution better than skewed distribution for machine learning input features?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, normal-distribution, skewness

Distribution of a particular feature in my ML dataset is skewed as shown below.
[image]

Log of this feature looks like a normal distribution.
[image]

Can the latter distribution offer better predictability in a neural network model?

P.S. Rest of my features in the dataset are like normal distribution and I applied z-score normalization.

(Addon qn: Is there a thumb rule like it's better to have normal-like or uniform-like distribution for ML predictability?)

Comment: Your plots look like time-series plots, are they?

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen , it's not a time series plot. Along y axis I have the value of a scalar feature from my dataset. Along x I have examples in the dataset.

Comment: OK. If by examples you mean "responses" or y-value, it is more usual to show those on the y-axis. Nevertheless, there is no indication of any problems in your plots. There is no specific assumptio9ns on the distribution of the features in thye usual ML/regression models, as thei con dition on the x-values. For specific advise, you need to tell us much more.